# Unable to send mails from gmail smtp

Tags: php

I am using Gmail SMTP for sending emails in php. The code is working fine in one of my client website. When I am using the same code for another client website, I am getting an error like "Could not authenticate, SMTP connect() failed.

> https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting"

. I don't have knowledge in server settings. Both websites are on different servers. Please check the below code.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

//$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';                
$mail->Password = 'password';                          
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                           
$mail->Port = 465;  // for tls 587

$mail->Subject = 'Test Email';

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Body = 'Message from test website';

$mail->setFrom('mahmood.bts@gmail.com');


$mail->addAddress('test@companyname.com');
$mail->addCC('info@companyname.com');

if($mail->send())
    echo "mail is sent";

    else 
      echo $mail->ErrorInfo;

 ?>
```

I used php mail function instead of SMTP, Then also I am unable to send emails. Please help me.

Comment: what is error ? Please check how to ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to allow untrusted apps from `mahmood.bts@gmail.com` account.

Comment: But is working another website without this setting. Anyway i will change this and test again.

Comment: Is my code is correct? or if there is any another way to send mails, Please explain me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer Gmail Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549304/phpmailer-gmail-server-error)

Comment: Do not send emails this way with a different `From` address, than the one you are authenticating against - that is asking for trouble with spam filters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Answer (score 1):

You should allow sending emails from an [untrusted app](https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account/).

> Google may block sign-in attempts from some apps or devices that do
>   not use modern security standards. Since these apps and devices are
>   easier to break into, blocking them helps keep your account safe.

To disable this security feature:

- Sign in to Gmail
- Click here to access Less Secure App Access in My
  Account.
- Next to “*Allow less secure apps: **OFF***”, select the toggle
  switch to turn **ON**.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21986973)

Comment: @taras Ok, I will include the most import content from the link in my answer