# problems with server SMTP PHPMailer

Tags: phpmailer

I have a problem with phpmailer, I have the correct SMPT server data and also the username and password, but it still marks me an error in the credentials, this is my code

```
  <?php 
include ("class.phpmailer.php");
include ("../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailer.php");
include ("../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP");
 // Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
    // These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
    require '../vendor/autoload.php';

    $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
    $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
    $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
    $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));


    // Load Composer's autoloader


    // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {

     //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
     $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
     $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
     $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
     $mail->Username   = 'admin@ucarolina.mx';                     // SMTP username
     $mail->Password   = '******';                             // SMTP password
     $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TSL';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
     $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to


        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('luribe@qvoz.com');
        $mail->addAddress($email, $name);     // Add a recipient


        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $contact_message;
        $mail->AltBody = $contact_message;

        $mail->send();
       echo "Mensaje enviado";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }


?>
```

and this is the error that marks me 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Comment: Can you try changing `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TSL'; ` to `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS'; ` and try again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer Gmail Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549304/phpmailer-gmail-server-error)

Comment: @zedfoxus I no longer see the error message but the emails do not arrive

Comment: Change `$mail->send();` to `if(!$mail->send()) { echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; } else { echo 'Message sent.'; }`. Run the script again and let me know whether you get Mailer error or Message sent.

Comment: @zedfoxus I could solve it, I had the reverse 2 lines, instead of reaching the mail, it came to the email they put in the form, but I could correct it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Wonderful. You should close out your question. There are 2 ways you can close your question. (1) I can put an answer and you accept that answer or (2) You answer your own question and then mark it as accepted. Which method would you prefer?

Comment: @zedfoxus You can put the answer and I accept it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a line where SMTPSecure has to be specified. You have that line, but `tls` has been mistyped as `TSL`. Let's change that:

Change

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TSL';
```

to

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Additionally, you should add an if/then surrounding `$mail->send();` like so:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

If the mail is not sent, your `if` statement will catch that and report the error. See an example of such error handling in PHPMailer example: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps